# Inserting into an ORACLE table that has an auto increment sequence from another table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, insert

I have an ORACLE database with two tables, one is an import of old data and another is "address"

I have set up the "address" table to auto increment using the following code:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE AddressID 
MINVALUE 1 START WITH 1 
CACHE 10;
```

I have to insert all the values from the same named columns from a table called "IMPORT_EMPLOYEE" but I can't get it to do that. This is what I have tried so far:

```
  INSERT INTO ADDRESS (ADDRESS.NEXTVAL,StreetAddress, City, Province, PostalCode)
SELECT StreetAddress, City, Province, PostalCode
FROM IMPORT_EMPLOYEE;
```

This returns the following error and I suspect this is because of the address.nextval:

Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 13
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values
00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"
*Cause:
*Action:

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: AddressID or ADDRESS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the sequence to the wrong place; should've been in `select`, while `insert into` should contain the "target" column (let's presume its name is `id`):

```
INSERT INTO address (
    id,
    streetaddress,
    city,
    province,
    postalcode
)
    SELECT
        address.NEXTVAL,
        streetaddress,
        city,
        province,
        postalcode
    FROM
        import_employee
```

---

Error you got - if everything else was OK - means that you're inserting 4 values into 5 columns, and that's a mismatch.

Comment: As a non-Oracle guy I'd consider using a sequence nextval as column default. I guess that can be done too?

Comment: Thank you so much! This took me hours to figure out and I swear I tried this very thing but must have mistyped in my frustration. I can't upvote due to the age of my account but thank you so much!

Comment: @jarlh: not as a default value, but (pre-12c) using a database trigger (which uses the sequence), or (12c and later) using an identity column. Steven, you're welcome.